# regex check for global group validation (js)

Tags: javascript, regex

hi i need to check the validity of all 'groups' and the mixed possibility of creating a word.

for example: (base word: asd)

```
asd
a s d
4 s   d
444ssddd
aaaaa444ssss dddd
```

must all match.
while a word that can contain it but have differente chars inside:

```
aesd
zxaxvd
```

must not match, anything that have not that pattern

i've try with something like this:

```
(a*|4*|4* *|a* *)(s*|s* *)(d*|d* *)
```

but this always return true, while should match the entire pattern group:

```
const regex = '(a*|4*|4* *|a* *)(s*|s* *)(d*|d* *)';
const re = new RegExp(regex, "gi");
const deleteMessage = re.test(text);
```

Comment: What are the rules for a match exactly, I can't tell what they are from the test cases?

Comment: In your first sentence you refer to "groups" without defining what they are are, "validity" without giving validation criteria, "mixed probability" without defining what that means and what statistical process is as work, and "creating a <sic> word" without explaining the construction process.

Comment: i was trying to match a world with different possible missmatch o replaced character for example for a banning process. ex. test->t3st->t32t->t e s t

Comment: When you say "world" do you mean "word"?  I'm confused what you mean by "world".

Comment: yes sorry i will correct the grammar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your regex:

1. everything is optional, so it will match an empty string;
2. because you don't have any anchors on your regex, it will thus match every input (since all strings have empty strings in them).

You can fix that by using this regex:

```
^(?:a*4+|a+4*) *s+ *d+ *$
```

which matches:

- `^` : beginning of string
- `(?:a*4+|a+4*)` : 0 or more `a` followed by 1 or more `4`; or 1 or more `a` followed by 0 or more `4`
- `*` : some number of spaces
- `s+` : 1 or more `s`
- `*` : some number of spaces
- `d+` : 1 or more `d`
- `*` : some number of spaces
- `$` : end of string

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Lr4hFP/2)

Comment: ok i think i understand what was wrong, i have missed the (?: ) for group the possible different cases and the mandatory of the chars, for example for the word "test" https://regex101.com/r/O9U8z8/2

Comment: it's better writhing (?:a*4+|a+4*) or as the below answer [a4]+ ? i've tested that too and it seems to work in the same way. Thanks

Comment: @Dekron you can just use `()` rather than `(?:)` but if you don't want the contents of the capture group then a non-capturing group `(?:)` is more efficient.

Comment: @Dekron it depends on what you want to match. I've assumed from your sample data that it is some number of `a` followed by some number of `4` and that is only what my regex will match, using `[a4]+` will match what is in your sample data but also something like `4aa44aa4`.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern has no bounds and doesn't actually require anything because it uses asterisks for everything, so even an empty string is valid. This should do the trick by adding start and end bounds as well as requiring at least one character from each grouping.

```
^([a4]+ *)(s+ *)(d+ *)$
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```js
const words=`asd
a s d
 a a 4  as      dd    d  
4 s   d
444ssddd
aaaaa444ssss dddd
aesd
zxaxvd
aa a s4s    d d`.split("\n");

words.forEach(w=>console.log(w,w.match(/^ *[a4][a4 ]*s[s ]*d[d ]*$/)));
```

In your regexp you used the `*` quantifier which also allows zero occurrences, while in my pattern I require at least *one* occurrence of the letters `a` or `4`, `s` and `d`.